# Json array in mongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb

I want to get objects according to an ID they have in an array in a json file in mongodb.
I tried a lot of ways to get them with no success:

```
db.collection.find({"Id":"2"})
db.collection.find({"Messages.Id":"2"})
db.collection.find({"Messages":{$elemMatch:{"Id":"2"}}})
db.collection.find({"Messages.Id":{$elemMatch:{"Id":"2"}}})

{
    "Messages" : [ 
        {
             "text":"aaa",
             "Id" : [ "1", "2" ] 
        }, 
        {
             "texts" : "bbb",
             "Id" : [ "1", "3" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Even though that's how it's supposed to be done according to the mongodb documentation.
So I thought something was wrong with my json design (I tried changing it but that didn't help either).
Can anyone suggest to me a good design or query to get the objects with a certain id will work?

UPDATE:
I want for example that if in the query i request the id 2
only the first message and all of it will be displayed (I don't mind if the Id field wont be displayed)

```
{
    "text":"aaa",
    "Id":["1","2"]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find single elements that match you will need to utilize the [positional operator ($)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/).

```
db.collection.find({"Messages.Id": "2"}, {"Messages.$": 1, _id: 0})
```

For finding multiple matches, you would use the [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$Messages" },
    { $match: {"Messages.Id": "1"}},
    { $group: { _id: null, messages: { $push: "$Messages"}}}
])
```

Comment: It didnt return anything, but i'll keep looking into this opertaor

Comment: I have another question. I see all the examples in mongodb have json that looks like that : {}{}{}{} objects with no commas seperating them. I tried doing so and it didnt work. is it on purpose , or i'm doing it wrong?

Comment: I dont know why it doesnt work..the syntax is the same. maybe because the id is inside an array that's also inside an array.
And I was talking about the examples in mongodb that looks like
`{ "_id" : 1, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 70, 87, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 90, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "semester" : 1, "grades" : [ 85, 100, 90 ] }
{ "_id" : 4, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 79, 85, 80 ] }
{ "_id" : 5, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 88, 88, 92 ] }
{ "_id" : 6, "semester" : 2, "grades" : [ 95, 90, 96 ] }`

Comment: there is no comma between the objects (between elements there are)

Comment: Oh.., I apparently changd something as I was trying to make it work and didnt notice.Thank you! But it only returned me one reuslt when i entered 1

Comment: but 2 Messages that have id=1